# NSPersistentDocument – how to access the window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspersistentdocument

I want to set some properties of the window of my NSPersistentDocument object. How do I get access to it?

Is there a better way than like this?

```
    [[[[self windowControllers] objectAtIndex:0] window] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's the way to get it. The `NSWindowController` is responsible for managing the window, and that's why it owns the window.

If you're customizing the window appearance or behavior, it would actually be better to subclass `NSWindowController` and put the code the customizes the window in that class, rather than your `NSDocument`/`NSPersistentDocument` subclass.

`NSDocument` (and friends) are meant to manage the data, and `NSWindowController` is meant to manage the UI. In all but the simplest applications, you should be subclassing `NSWindowController`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `self.windowForSheet` which seems to be working.